# spring security permit all considering basic auth passed and validating it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am doing POC on spring security recently and saw some strange behavior. API endpoint configured as permit all is authenticating the request if client calls this endpoint using basic auth.
Sample code:

```
http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().and()
        .formLogin().disable();
        return http.build();
```

Calling using curl as below is giving error:

```
curl -X GET -u "user:password" -H Content-Type:application/json http://localhost:20000/health
```

Error:

```
{"responseCode":401,"responseStatus":"Unauthorized","errorMessage":["Not authorized to access"],"responseMsg":null}
```

And if called without and user and password in above curl command then it works and return the desired response.
Can anyone please suggest if this is correct behavior and how to override it.

Auth entrypoint implementation:

```
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData.setResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        responseData.setErrorMessage(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Not authorized to access")));
        responseData.setResponseCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

          ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
          String jsonResponse = mapper.writeValueAsString(responseData);
          PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter(); 
          printWriter.append(jsonResponse);
             printWriter.flush();
             printWriter.close();
      }
}
```

Comment: You didn't configure the user. Show your full configuration.

Comment: Basically, this means you are not authorized accessing /health endpoint with basic authentication. Could you, please, share entryPoint implementation?

Comment: @dur do we need to configure the user in this scenario? In my configuration have told clearly to permit GET /health endpoint. So the question here is why it is getting validated?

Comment: @tohhant2 Added entryPoint implementation above

Comment: @Smith If you send a username and password it will checked. If you don*t configure users, then you should not send username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`permitAll` does not mean that there is no authentication, it just states that there will be no authorization checks for that endpoint. Therefore, if you have `httpBasic` enabled and send the credentials in the request, the credentials will be checked by the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` against your `UserDetailsService`.

I assume that your credentials are wrong and that's why you are receiving a 401.